# Which TortoiseGit command can overwrite local files?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I've installed TortoiseGit on Windows. I want to fetch all code from `origin/master` and all local files may be overwritten.
How can we do this with right clicking on the folder and which TortoiseGit method we should use with parameters?
Or do we always need to open a command prompt and enter the following commands:

```
git fetch --all
get reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseGit has almost all the same features as command line, so most of the time the command line is not needed.

> ```
> git fetch --all
> ```

Use the fetch dialog, when there are multiple remotes, then you could choose "- all -"

[image: Fetch]

> ```
>  git reset --hard origin/master
> ```

You need to go to the log, choose origin/master (on the left) and select reset in the contextmenu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exact same operations in TortoiseGit:

*Fetch*, then you can open the log and to a *reset* on `origin/master` using the context menu (if the branch is not visible, you can show it by enabling "Show all branches in the lower left or selecting it on the branch selector in the obber left).

If you don't have any local changes or commits, you can also just `pull`.